# Calling a method with System.Data.Linq.Table<T> parameter throws error: type arguments inferred

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here is my method:

```
 private bool IsCorrect<T>(System.Data.Linq.Table<T> table) where T : class
    {
        return true;
    }

    private bool CheckIfCorrect()
    {
        return IsCorrect(db.myTable);
    }

    private bool CheckIfOk()
    {
        return IsCorrect(db.myOtherTable);
    }
```

Where myTable is a database table, and db is ObjectContext (it's the entity model).

I'm getting syntax error: The type arguments for method `IsCorrect<T>(System.Data.Linq.Table<T>`) cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. How to call this method?

Comment: What are the compile-time types of `db.myTable` and `db.myOtherTable`?

Comment: How are `db.myTable` and `db.myOtherTable` defined?

Comment: @JonSkeet ObjectSet<myOtherTable> and ObjectSet<myTable>.

Comment: @MarcGravell ObjectSet<myOtherTable> and ObjectSet<myTable>

Comment: @petko_stankoski: Well `ObjectSet<T>` doesn't derive from `Table<T>`... so it looks like it's simply an invalid call. Did you mean to actually make the parameter `IQueryable<T>` perhaps?

Comment: @petko_stankoski `ObjectSet<T>` has no direct relationship to `Table<T>`, unless you go via `IQueryable<T>` etc. What is it you *expect* it to do, if you are passing an `ObjectSet<T>` to something that expects a `Table<T>` ?

Comment: @JonSkeet Will changing the method signature from Table to ObjectSet solve the issue?

Comment: @petko_stankoski: It's hard to know as we've no idea what you want to do in the method. It will make it compile with the code you've presented, I'd expect... but that's not the same as it being the right thing to do.

Comment: At the very least it looks like you have confused Linq to SQL with Linq to EF.